# Difference between present perfect continuous and present participle form in refering to regulation continued to the present

Tags: grammar

I'm giving two examples. I know we can use them in exchange but I want to know if there is any difference between them in professional point of view.

> 1. Presently, it is 3 months that **we have been  working on it**.
> 2. Presently, it is 3 months that **we are working on it**.

Answer (score 1):

"Presently, it is 3 months that we have been working on it." appears to be more appropriate sentence. For present perfect continuous, you've got the 
"have been" (habitual particle) element and the present "working" element. 

If I may add, this would be more concise sentence if you made it " it has been three months since we have been working on it."

Comment: Thank you that is exactly true. but I still don't know why people use the second form...maybe it's just easier to say the second form!

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence isn't grammatically correct because the main idea of Present Continuous Tense, which is used there, is to express 'incompleted present process at /or around/ the moment of speech'. The first sentence is about 'incompleted past process up to the moment of speech'. That's why the first sentence is grammatically correct.